# waking from suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, radeon

On waking Ubuntu 16.04 from suspend, I notice this black screen.

[image]

Can anyone please explain this? This is not causing any issues, but I need to know what's happening.

Comment: The solution mentioned above says you need to remove acpid, but will it cause any issues?

Comment: If it makes matters worse then use `sudo apt install acpid`.